# Recently DELETE and PUT API of default magento 2 was not working, are these the permission issue?

Tags: magento, magento2.2, magento2.1

I call API through Postman.
API - PUT rest/V1/customers/144 was not working , It was successfully work on my Local but not on test environment, After some time I came to know that all PUT and DELETE APIs are not working.

Ii displays Error 404:Not found.

```
<!doctype html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ><head>
<title>Error 404: Not Found</title>
<base href="http://shoppingtest.eduqfix.com/pub/errors/default/" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="robots" content="*"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <main class="page-main">
        <h1>404 error: Page not found.</h1>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you change anything in default magento functionality?

Comment: Not Actually , But same code is running on local machine perfectly

Comment: Can you check log files?

Comment: no log generated inside magento @Jinesh

Comment: can you tell me what data pass into this api PUT rest/V1/customers/144